# ¿Como hacer que una caja siempre aparezca con el máximo de scroll?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, scroll

Uso vue y vuetify. 
Lo que estoy haciendo es un chat, quiero que cuando abran el chat aparezca con todo el scroll posible

Esta es la única idea que tengo.

```
document.getElementById('scroll-target').scrollTo(0, 10000000);
```

Pero no hace el scroll en la caja.

Comment: Creo que lo que necesitas es CSS, en vez de javascript. Puedes crear un contenedor que ocupe el alto total del navegador con esta propiedad: `height: 100vh`

Comment: nop por que en los chats se van agregando el historial cuando van haciendo scroll hacia arriba. O cuando se agregan nuevos mensajes. Aun asi lo solucione con un listener en mi objeto (que guarda el chat)

Comment: Ahora te entendí, quieres tener el último mensaje (el de más abajo), en vez de el primero. Es correcta tu propuesta.

Answer (score 2):

Podrías intentar hacer un "onLoad" en el "body" del chat, es decir:

```
<body onLoad="funcionAbajo()"></body>
```

Y en el JS usar el siguiente código:

```
function funcionAbajo(){

window.scroll({
  top: document.body.scrollHeight,//con esto detecta la altura total del componente para bajar
  behavior: 'smooth'
});
}
```

Comment: gracias. Utilice una función muy parecida, pero en esencia es lo que aconsejas.